# Can we change the logging level of a single log-statement during run-time?

Tags: java, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I have the following code:

```
private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
if (LOGGER.isErrorEnabled()) {
    LOGGER.error("ID_1: Log Message: " + parameter));
}
```

And I want the severity to be set to `WARN` or `FATAL`.

If I am able to update the log4j.properties during run-time, then how would I change the severity of this message? Using `log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN` will only change the severity for an entire package.

Is there a way to be more specific?
Can we change the logging level of a single logging statement during run-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is No you can't.

To do what you want to do, you would need to **change the code** to call the Logger method that takes a Level as an argument, and replace the guard; e.g.

```
if (logger.isEnabledFor(level)) {
    logger.log(level, "ID_1: Log Message: " + parameter, null);
}
```

And I don't think this is going to help because you then have the problem of getting the right value into that `level` variable.

A better alternative would be to create a logger with a unique name, and only use in that particular statement.  Then you can control logging of that statement (via the logging configs) independently of any other statements.

Or, more realistically, use class names or package names to name your loggers.  That gives you more granularity than a single global logger ... without creating an insane number of Logger instances.

Comment: The reason why changing the code to use a log-level is a problem is because we have hundreds of components which would need to be changed. But thanks for the short answer.

Comment: @mahler - Making large scale changes like this is not as unrealistic as you might imagine.  In fact, the changes man be done pretty mechanically ... if not in a fully / mostly automated fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the LogLevel when using Log4j and the log-methods, which take a LogLevel as a parameter:

```
Logger l = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
l.log(Level.WARN, message);
l.log(Level.ERROR, message);
l.log(Level.ERROR, message, throwable);
```